# How to get remote url content using HttpURLConnection in android?

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I am trying to get remote url content using HttpURLConnection but i keep getting empty result.By looking at charle proxy i can see the get request is executed but android can't save the response!Could you guys tell me what is wrong with this code ?Thanks in advance.

```
public String sendGetRequest() {


        try {

            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new Builder().permitAll().build());

            HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL("http://www.bbc.com").openConnection();
            myURLConnection.setReadTimeout(60000);
            myURLConnection.setConnectTimeout(60000);
            myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 6.0;)");

            myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            myURLConnection.addRequestProperty("Content-length", "");

            OutputStream os = myURLConnection.getOutputStream();

            os.close();

            myURLConnection.connect();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(myURLConnection.getInputStream()));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line;


            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                sb.append(line);

            }


            in.close();

            return sb.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return null;

    }
```

and i call the above function from onclick of a button:

```
public Button but1;

//creating public method
public void init() {

but1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.but1);


//wire our button
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {



        String finalResult = sendGetRequest();
        mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:displayIt(" + finalResult+ ")");
    }
});
```

}

Edit(used background process):

```
 public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

            try {

                url = new URL(urls[0]);

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while (data != -1) {

                    char current = (char) data;

                    result += current;

                    data = reader.read();

                }

                return result;

            } catch (Exception e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

                return "Failed";

            }


        }

    }
```

Comment: setDoOutput is for POST requests, and you are getting it bebfore opening connection also, dont know the expected result, also, why the URL is a javascript?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the exception:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I'm sure It's because you are doing long operation on your main thread.

You must do long operations in the background thread.

Refer to this documentation :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html

**Update using your updated question**

If you created the AsyncTask inside your Activity , you could use this else you should create an Interface class an pass in the constructor of your AsyncTask

```
but1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         new DownloadTask().execute("http://www.bbc.com");
    }
});

     public class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {



 @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    String result = "";
    URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;

    try {

        url = new URL(urls[0]);

        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

        int data = reader.read();

        while (data != -1) {

            char current = (char) data;

            result += current;

            data = reader.read();

        }

        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return "Failed";

    }


}


@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result){
    mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:displayIt('" + result+ "')");
}

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. But how to transfer the response from protected String doInBackground(String... urls) { to webview without skipping frames ? I tried to make the get request inside doInBackground(String... urls) { but don't know how to send the response to webView UI!

Comment: Use the onPostExecute method to refresh your UI

Comment: I updated my first post . could you look at it and show me how i can use onPostExecute to pass the result to webview javascript function?

Comment: I want to fetch a m3u list from url in my website and i keep getting following error. is there any solution for it ?error I/Choreographer: Skipped 10132 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
I/Choreographer: Skipped 690 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.

Comment: does this solution work for you? what is the error? give us more detail  , "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread" this message is because you are doing long operations in the main thread

Comment: The application is loading a webview then when i press a button it should fetch the url and put it in textarea on webview. clicking a button is considered a long operation ?

Comment: fetch the url  is considered a long operation :) , what is wrong with my solution? I don't understand

Comment: i had to  change  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:displayIt(" + result+ ")"); to  mWebView.loadUrl("javascript:displayIt('" + result + "');"); and now i am successfully can pull date from web .If i want to call DownloadTask onload of mainAcitivty where should i call it after webview finished loading?

Comment: put your updated code, btw , using  StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new Builder().permitAll().build());  is not the correct way to to asynchronous tasks

Comment: Thanks is there a way not to output the result in one line ? i want to keep the format of original remote content (for example keeping all the line breaks)?Currently it outputs the result all in one line removing all the break lines!I want to keep the break lines!

Comment: Yes, change how are you reading the data, and read line by line

Comment: so how to detect new line from variable sb and add it to end of result += current; => result += current+newline;